# How to get bgcolored td's to stretch to fit

Tags: html, css, email

Working on a template that needs to work in Outlook 365. Not sure why the orange lines are not stretching to fill in the space. This is for an HTML email so can't use Divs.

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/HkDyx

[image]

```
<td style="100%" height="1">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr><td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#f67b1e"></td></tr>
  </table>
  <!-- <hr style="width: 100%; border-right: 0; border-left: 0; border: 1px solid #f67b1e;"> -->
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go just have the declare the width of those lines

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" bgcolor="gray"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="wants_an_intro" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; color:#006497; text-align:center; font-size:24px; color: #f67b1e; width: 100%;">

    <td style="width:30%" height="1"> <!-- width:30% -->
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr><td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#f67b1e"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <!-- <hr style="width: 100%; border-right: 0; border-left: 0; border: 1px solid #f67b1e;"> -->
    </td>

    <td style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:1em; color:#f67b1e;">wants an intro to</td>

    <td style="width:30%" height="1"> <!-- width:30% -->
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr><td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#f67b1e"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <!-- <hr style="width: 100%; border-right: 0; border-left: 0; border: 1px solid #f67b1e;"> -->
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" bgcolor="gray"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or --------

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" bgcolor="gray"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="wants_an_intro" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; color:#006497; text-align:center; font-size:24px; color: #f67b1e; width: 100%;">

    <td  width="30%" style="" height="1">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr><td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#f67b1e"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <!-- <hr style="width: 100%; border-right: 0; border-left: 0; border: 1px solid #f67b1e;"> -->
    </td>

    <td style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size:1em; color:#f67b1e;">wants an intro to</td>

    <td width="30%" style="" height="1">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr><td width="100%" height="1" bgcolor="#f67b1e"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <!-- <hr style="width: 100%; border-right: 0; border-left: 0; border: 1px solid #f67b1e;"> -->
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="20" bgcolor="gray"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: omg I thought I did... this is what I get for working super late lol, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Just set `width` to the `td` of the two lines or one line and the text depends of what you want

View the demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/racJt**